# Two simple counterexamples in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, intersection-theory

Suppose we have a smooth complex algebraic variety $X$. Then in general, $K^a(X)\to K(X^{an})$ is not surjective. Could someone give an example of a topological vector bundle class which contains no algebraic vector bundles?

In a similar spirit, what is an example of a homology class in $H_{2*}(X^{an})$ representable by a combination of submanifolds, but not in the image of $A^*(X)$ (i.e. not representable by a combination of submanifolds which are the analytifications of subvarieties)?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_conjecture).

Comment: For the second question, let me answer the dual question about cohomology. Cohomology classes of subvarieties always lie in the middle summand $H^{p,p}$ of the Hodge decomposition of $H^{2p}(X,\mathbf C)$. But many varieties have integer classes that don't lie in that summand. For example on a $K3$ surface, $H^2(X,\mathbf Z)$ is a lattice of rank 22. But the sublattice $H^2(X,\mathbf Z) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$ spanned by classes of curves has rank anywhwere between 1 and 20. So there are lots of leftover classes.

Comment: Ah I see - I'd forgotten about that tidbit about the Hodge decomposition. Thank you! And thanks a lot for the link Kevin.

Comment: For the first question, see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7304/complex-vector-bundles-that-are-not-holomorphic for some references. (There is also some information there about a more refined kind of answer to the second question.)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So one would try to reverse engineer counterexamples to the integral Hodge conjecture into complex bundles with no holomorphic (hence algebraic) structure?